# Is Spectral Theory necessary to show that QM operators are densely defined, essentially self-adjoined?

Tags: mathematical-physics, spectral-theory, quantum-mechanics

I'm reading Hall's *Quantum Theory for Mathematicians*, and I merely wish to check my understanding on a small thing:

Spectral Theory is needed to show that QM operators (e.g. the position or momentum operators) are defined on dense subsets of the Hilbert space $L^2(\mathbb{R})$ and are (essentially) self-adjoint.

**Right?**

Comment: I would not say so. In fact i would say that it is exactly opposite: To use many results from spectral theory we need a self-adjoint operator.

Comment: @jd27 I see. I got the impression Spectral Theory was needed since, in Chapter 3, Hall explains that the treatment of the domains of the operators is postponed to Chapter 9 (which is the third chapter dealing with Spectral Theory).

Comment: You could take that as an axiom of Quantum Mechanics. You have commutator relations, etc., and those determines representations as operators on a Hilbert space. It's not so much that Mathematics provides a framework, but rather the axioms of Quantum Mechanics provide a way to build such a framework. At least that was how it was presented to me.